# linearly independent solutions and general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question can be tagged as off-topic. But just out of curiosity, I want to know what is the physical significance of the linearly independent solutions of a differential equation. Also what do we get physically by working out the general solution of such an equation.

Comment: Not necessarily off topic but certainly unclear. What do you mean by "physical significance" and "get physically"? The $n$ independent solutions are there cause there are $n$ independent initial conditions that can be set. This certainly has a physical interpretation. In a second order ode like newton's eq of motion, the initial position and velocity determine the motion. When you work out the general solution to such an equation you get tired physically.

Comment: Your question indeed is off-topic...

Still, the best example is perhaps that of two solutions of the linear wave equation. Linear independence means that one wave doesn't "see" the other wave, and that one can pass by the other without ever changing their profiles.

Do have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle.

On the other hand, the physical interpretation of nonlinear equations is extremely complicated, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_Schrödinger_equation, when compared to the extremely simple interpretation in the linear case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just a short answer: linear independence allows us to not "repeat" solutions, and the general solution tells us what sort of family the solutions fall under. For example, for the equation $y'' + y = 0$, our solutions are sines and cosines - any linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ gives us all solutions of this differential equation.